# Combining Columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I've write a `SQL` code to combine several `columns` from different tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT PD_BARCODE
    FROM docsadm.PD_BARCODE
    WHERE SYSTEM_ID = 11660081
) t,
(
    SELECT A_JAHRE
    FROM docsadm.A_PD_DATENSCHUTZ
    WHERE system_ID = 2066
) t2,
(
    SELECT PD_PART_NAME
    FROM docsadm.PD_FILE_PART
    WHERE system_id = 11660082
) t3;
```

code works fine but if one of my where clause is not found in a table,the result is null even the other columns have value. How you can solve this problem?

Comment: No join conditions?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a cross join between the three subquery tables.  This would probably only yield output which makes sense if each subquery return a single value.  I might suggest instead that you use a `UNION ALL` here:

```
SELECT ISNULL(PD_BARCODE, 'NA' AS value
FROM docsadm.PD_BARCODE WHERE SYSTEM_ID = 11660081
UNION ALL
SELECT ISNULL(A_JAHRE, 'NA')
FROM docsadm.A_PD_DATENSCHUTZ WHERE system_ID = 2066
UNION ALL
SELECT ISULL(PD_PART_NAME, 'NA')
FROM docsadm.PD_FILE_PART WHERE system_id = 11660082
```

The above union query might require a slight modification if the three columns being select don't all have the same type (which I assume to be `varchar` in my query).

If you really need these three points of data as separate columns, then you can just include the three subqueries as items in an outer select:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT ISNULL(PD_BARCODE, 'NA')
     FROM docsadm.PD_BARCODE WHERE SYSTEM_ID = 11660081) AS PD_BARCODE,
    (SELECT ISNULL(A_JAHRE, 'NA')
     FROM docsadm.A_PD_DATENSCHUTZ WHERE system_ID = 2066) AS A_JAHRE,
    (SELECT ISNULL(PD_PART_NAME, 'NA')
     FROM docsadm.PD_FILE_PART WHERE system_id = 11660082) AS PD_PART_NAME;
```

Note that as the above is written we simply including the subqueries as values in the select statement.  But as you wrote your original query, you are joining the subqueries as separate tables.

Comment: @ertan2002 If the first query gives an error, it could be because the types of the columns are not the same.  In that case, we could try casting everything to `varchar` for display purposes.

Comment: I have problem with this  part => SELECT ISNULL(PD_BARCODE, 'NA' AS value   and you wrote ISULL but i fixed it and u missed parantesis but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Here is `Query`.

You can replace the word '`empty`' by your required word or value

```
SELECT isnull(
             (
                 SELECT PD_BARCODE
                 FROM docsadm.PD_BARCODE
                 WHERE SYSTEM_ID = 11660081
             ), 'Empty') AS PD_BARCODE,
       isnull(
             (
                 SELECT A_JAHRE
                 FROM docsadm.A_PD_DATENSCHUTZ
                 WHERE system_ID = 2066
             ), 'Empty') AS A_JAHRE,
       isnull(
             (
                 SELECT PD_PART_NAME
                 FROM docsadm.PD_FILE_PART
                 WHERE system_id = 11660082
             ), 'Empty') AS PD_PART_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case since you would be getting only one value per query of yours which you are trying to put up as column. In this case, you can use SQL [PIVOT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) with UNION ALL of your queries like shown below. MIN can be used for aggregation in this case.

This would mean, you can get your data row-wise as you like, even for multiple different fields and then pivot it into columns in one go.

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (
   SELECT 'PD_BARCODE' as KeyItem, PD_BARCODE Name from docsadm.PD_BARCODE 
   where SYSTEM_ID=11660081

   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A_JAHRE', A_JAHRE from docsadm.A_PD_DATENSCHUTZ 
   where system_ID=2066

   UNION ALL
   select 'PD_PART_NAME', PD_PART_NAME from docsadm.PD_FILE_PART 
   where system_id=11660082

 ) VTABLE
PIVOT(MIN(Name) 
     FOR KeyItem IN ([PD_BARCODE], [A_JAHRE], [PD_PART_NAME])) as pivotData;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation. using pivot is better ? because the other queries also working

Comment: It basically depends on the execution plan generated by queries. I would suggest you check each query for actual execution plan, and check the one which has best execution plan and data retrieval timings. No questions though, that this is more intuitive syntax for sql person to understand what exactly is happening in the query.

Comment: thank you again :) It suppose to return only one field because i am using system id and retrieving only one field from each table. I think there should be not so much performance problem..

Comment: No, should not be. But I would still suggest you to check actual execution plans. It can surprise sometimes.